# Hiding _all_ remote methods in loopback model

Tags: node.js, rest, loopback

I'm using loopback 3.
I have this lines of codes in my model's js (survey.js):

```
let enabledRemoteMethods = []

Survey.sharedClass.methods().forEach(function(method) {
  console.log(method.name, method.isStatic)
  let matchingEnabledRemoteMethod = _.find(enabledRemoteMethods, {name: method.name});

  if (!matchingEnabledRemoteMethod) {
    Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName(method.name, method.isStatic);
  }
});
```

It works.... almost. I could still see in the explorer the REST endpoint for "PATCH /surveys/{id}". My expectation is: there shouldn't be any REST endpoints listed in the explorer.

Then I examined the URL corresponding to that operation, it is:

http://localhost:3000/explorer/#!/Survey/Survey_prototype_patchAttributes

[image]

Which, according to the documentation, means that patchAttributes is a static method.

Then I cross checked with the output in the console... there it says: pathAttributes is *not* static.

Incosistency!

[image]

I even have tried adding this line:

```
Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName("patchAttributes", true);
```

Also

```
Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName("patchAttributes", false);
```

No luck.

Can someone confirm if it's a bug in loopback 3 (I don't know about loopback 2, haven't checked)? If it's a bug I wouldn't have to spend time on it and just wait until it gets fixed. But if it's not a bug, can someone point out what's missing in my code?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: figured out how

With this line I'm able to get rid of it:

```
Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName("prototype.patchAttributes", true);
```

The second parameter doesn't seem to matter (you can put false as well). Not sure why though (I suppose it should've accepted true only).

This is my current solution:

```
let disabledPrototypesRemoteMethods = ['patchAttributes']
let enabledRemoteMethods = [
  "create", "findById", "replaceById", "deleteById",
  "replaceOrCreateQuestion"
]
Survey.sharedClass.methods().forEach(function(method) {
  if (enabledRemoteMethods.indexOf(method.name) == -1) {
    Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName(method.name);
  }

  if (disabledPrototypesRemoteMethods.indexOf(method.name) > -1) {
    Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName("prototype." + method.name);
  }
});
```

Still, one small detail: this thing still shows up (I suppose it provides the POST alternative for the normal PUT for the replaceById operation..., but I don't want it; I want to force user of my API to go with the PUT only):

http://localhost:3000/explorer/#!/Survey/Survey_replaceById_post_surveys_id_replace

[image]

I tried adding this line:

```
Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName("replaceById_post_surveys_id_replace");
```

No luck.

Anyway... hope this useful for others; loopback doc is kind of sketchy.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the prototype methods as well by looking at the `stringName` property.  That way you can include the prototypes in your list.

The `stringName` includes the sharedClass name in the value, so you will need to parse that out.

```
module.exports = BusinessProfileContacted => {
  const enabledRemoteMethods = ["create", "findById", "replaceById", "deleteById", "replaceOrCreateQuestion", "prototype.replaceAttributes"];

  Survey.sharedClass.methods().forEach(method => {
    const methodName = method.stringName.replace(/.*?(?=\.)/, '').substr(1);
    if (enabledRemoteMethods.indexOf(methodName) === -1) {
      Survey.disableRemoteMethodByName(methodName);
    }
  });
};
```